# Pyramid, Javascript: I get HTML numbers instead of quotes

Tags: javascript, python, knockout.js, pyramid, mako

I return the dict as follows from **pyramid** view:

```
return {'details': json.dumps(details)}
```

From a **mako** template, I access the variable as:

```
var a = ${details};
```

But Javascript throws `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &` because the quotes used in `details` are converted into **HTML numbers**(`&#34;`).

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [documentation of the filtering](http://docs.makotemplates.org/en/latest/filtering.html) in Mako:

You need use the `n` filter to disable all the filters declared in the `<%page>` tag as well as in `default_filters` (which contains the HTML escaping filter `h` by default)

So you need to write

```
var a = ${details | n};
```